# Mysql Load File

Tags: mysql

I have a CSV file containing one line for each row in a Mysql DB table; there are 3 values in each line. The first 2 correspond directly to columns of the DB table, so can be passed through. The third value contains a code that is to be used as a "lookup" code into a different DB Table and another column (1:1 relationship) in that table is to be loaded into the first table. So:

- Table1: contains ColA, ColB, ColC
- Table2: contains LookupCode, LookupValue

CSV file contains (on each line) ColA, ColB, LookupCode

What I want to load into Table1 via the CSV file is: ColA, ColB, LookupValue FROM Table2 based on the LookupCode in column 3 of the CSV file line.

My question is: how do I do this?

I tried a LOAD DATA statement of the following form:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path to CSV file' INTO TABLE Table1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(ColA, ColB, @Lookup)
SET ColC = (SELECT LookupValue FROM Table2 WHERE LookupCode = @Lookup LIMIT 1);
```

but this resulted in NULL for ColC in every loaded row (ColA and ColB were fine).

If I use a fixed code instead of @Lookup, e.g. LookupCode = 'code1' it will access Table2 and populate the (same) corresponding column value, value1 in each loaded row's ColC, so the SELECT statement is being executed, but apparently cannot use a dynamic value.

As a work around, I guess I could add another column, ColD, to Table1 and store the LookupCode in it from the CSV file, then run a separate query to update the value of each rows ColC based on the value of ColD in conjunction with the SELECT clause; but I don't want ColD in Table1 and would rather fill in ColC directly.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why the query I was trying to use was not working. It had to do with the data in the CSV file. The third field was not properly delimited (not sure exactly why) and so contained non-displayable characters which were affecting the comparison in the SELECT clause of the query. When I did a global update on the CSV file to eliminate this problem, then the LOAD DATA query worked as expected.

Sorry for any inconvenience.